# How to achieve Date format SSRS Example 12Th Jan 2019

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Using expression, I'm able to get the date for mat like this in SSRS. Below is the expression : `=FORMAT(Cdate(today), "dd-MM-yyyy")`

However, I would like to see the date as: 12Th Jan 2019 or 1St Jan 2019 or 2nd Feb 2019.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't appear that `FORMAT` supports this out of the box.  [Here](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/sql-server/sql-how-to-output-ordinal-day-from-date-1st-2nd-3rd-4th/) is one way you can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Expression which Gives you desired Result.

```
=day(today) &
IIF((day(today))Mod 10=1 and  (day(today))Mod 100 <>11,
"st",
IIF((day(today))Mod 10=2 and  (day(today))Mod 100 <>12,
"nd",
IIF((day(today))Mod 10=3 and  (day(today))Mod 100 <>13,
"rd",
"th")
)
)
& " " & MonthName(Month(today)) & " "& Year(today)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a need for `and  (day(today))Mod 100 <>11` . It should work if you just use `and  day(today)  <>11` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date to format like

> 01 Mar 2019 06:21:58:010 By using below convertion
>
> SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),113)

but you can not convert like below directly

> 12Th Jan 2019 or 1St Jan 2019 or 2nd Feb 2019.

but you can achieve this by using the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Ufn_GetDateWithSelectedFormat]
(
    @Date DATETIME 
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DateValue NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),113))
    DECLARE @OnesPlaceNum INT = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,1,2))

    SET @DateValue = CASE WHEN (@OnesPlaceNum % 10 = 1 AND @OnesPlaceNum % 100 <> 11) THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,1,2)) + 'St' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,3,LEN(@DateValue)))
                      WHEN (@OnesPlaceNum % 10 = 2 @OnesPlaceNum % 100 <> 22) THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,1,2)) + 'Nd' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,3,LEN(@DateValue)))
                      WHEN (@OnesPlaceNum % 10 = 3 @OnesPlaceNum % 100 <> 33) THEN (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,1,2)) + 'Rd' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,3,LEN(@DateValue)))
                      ELSE (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,1,2)) + 'Nd' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DateValue,3,LEN(@DateValue))) END

RETURN @DateValue
END
GO
```

Then you can call this function like

> SELECT [dbo].Ufn_GetDateWithSelectedFormat
>   then you are getting the answer like 13Rd May 2019 11:40:50:343